# In GoCD mvn clean install is giving mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command but normal cmd project builds successfully

Tags: go-cd

In GoCD mvn clean install is giving error mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command but in normal cmd I am able to build the project successfully

**Error in GoCD build**

[image: Error in GoCD build]

**Normal build:**

[image: Normal build]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `mvn` is not in the `PATH` that the go-agent uses.

Try specifying an absolute path to the `mvn` execute in your GoCD task.